# jQuery inArray giving incorrect results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm just trying to check if a string exists in an array of strings.

```
console.log($.inArray(String(value.value), selectors) > 0, String(value.value), selectors);
```

The code above is giving me results that look like this

```
false "23" (2) ["23", "9"]
true "9" (2) ["23", "9"]
false "28" (2) ["23", "9"]
false "20" (2) ["23", "9"]
```

Without checking if `inArray` is equal to `> 0`, my results look like this

```
0 "23" (2) ["23", "9"]
1 "9" (2) ["23", "9"]
-1 "28" (2) ["23", "9"]
-1 "20" (2) ["23", "9"]
```

Why is the first one returning as false? How can I make it correctly determine if the string is in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.inArray()` returns the array position of the found element, or `-1`.

You wrote `> 0`, but you meant `> -1`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It happens. :)